# Resize elements to fit the current screensize using XAML for WP 8.1

Tags: xaml, gridview, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, screen-size

I'm making an app for Windows Phone 8.1 and I've run into some troubles with how the elements are displayed on the screen in different resolutions.

**My question is:** How can I display two columns with X number of rows, where the width of the columns will stretch to the side of the screen, no matter the screen size (for phones).

[1] Just to give you a visual example, this is how I want it to look, no matter the screen size (picture number [1]): (There are more rows below, but I removed them for this example).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNGMP.jpg

[2] However, on bigger screens (this case a 6-inch), the content does not stretch all the way out, as shown in picture number [2].

[3] I've tried adding a Viewbox around the content, but then the result is like picture number [3] in the imgur link (couldn't upload more than one link). It stretches out, but it doesn't give me two columns. I've tried setting a max width for the Viewbox as well, but it doesn't change anything.

My **XAML** code so far is:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <GridView x:Name="ContentGrid" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <GridView.Header>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Application name" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
            </GridView.Header>

            <!-- Row 1 -->
            <GridViewItem Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_1" Style="{StaticResource GridStyleOdd}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/Icons/Angle.png" Margin="0,-9,5,9" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Angle" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </GridViewItem>
            <GridViewItem Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_1" Style="{StaticResource GridStyleOdd}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/Icons/Area.png" Margin="0,-9,5,9" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Area" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </GridViewItem>

            <!-- Row 2 -->
            <GridViewItem Style="{StaticResource GridStyleEven}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/Icons/Fuel_Consumption.png" Margin="0,-9,5,9" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Consumption" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Margin="10,0,0,-23" Width="188" />
                </Grid>
            </GridViewItem>
            <GridViewItem Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_2" Style="{StaticResource GridStyleEven}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/Icons/Currency.png" Margin="0,-9,5,9" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Currency" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </GridViewItem>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size of one from the GridViewItems in code behind

e.x.

```
public MainPage()
    {
       //....


        var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
        double height = bounds.Height;
        double width = bounds.Width;

        gridViewitem1.Width = width * 0.5f;
        ContentGrid.Width = width;
    }
```

I've tested it on all sizes.

EDIT:

- You must change the width of the ContentGrid, too.
- And remove the grid, wich is in the Scrollviewer

  ```
  <ScrollViewer>

      <GridView x:Name="ContentGrid" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
          <GridView.Header>
              <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Application name" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
          </GridView.Header>

          <!-- Row 1 -->
          <GridViewItem x:Name="gridViewItem1" Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_1" Style="{StaticResource GridStyleOdd}">
              <Grid>
                  <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/Icons/Angle.png" Margin="0,-9,5,9" />
                  <TextBlock Text="Angle" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
              </Grid>
          </GridViewItem>
          <GridViewItem Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_1" Style="{StaticResource GridStyleOdd}">
              <Grid>
                  <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/Icons/Area.png" Margin="0,-9,5,9" />
                  <TextBlock Text="Area" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
              </Grid>
          </GridViewItem>

          <!-- Row 2 -->
          <GridViewItem Style="{StaticResource GridStyleEven}">
              <Grid>
                  <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/Icons/Fuel_Consumption.png" Margin="0,-9,5,9" />
                  <TextBlock Text="Consumption" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Margin="10,0,0,-23" Width="188" />
              </Grid>
          </GridViewItem>
          <GridViewItem Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped_2" Style="{StaticResource GridStyleEven}">
              <Grid>
                  <Image Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/Icons/Currency.png" Margin="0,-9,5,9" />
                  <TextBlock Text="Currency" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
              </Grid>
          </GridViewItem>
      </GridView>
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It worked perfectly (as you already pointed out).
 
 
 
I do have another question, though: Is it possible to do this with pure XAML if you structure the code another way?

Comment: I'm glad, that it works. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with XAML, so far. But I think you can do this with data bindings (Don't know how)